# ImageView setImageURI() не показывает изображение

Tags: android, kotlin

У меня в телефоне две папки **Card** и **Phone**. В папке **Card** я создал папку **MyPhoto** и поместил туда изображение **flap.png**. Это изображение я хочу вывести в ImageView. Ни один из вариантов не работает. Подскажите. Спасибо.

```
//1 вариант
var path: String = "file:///mnt/sdcard/MyPhoto/flap.png"

//2 вариант
//var path: String = "file://mnt/sdcard/MyPhoto/flap.png"

//3 вариант
//var path: String = "/mnt/sdcard/MyPhoto/flap.png"

imageView1.setImageURI(Uri.parse(path))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можете попробовать таким образом:

```
val file = File("/sdcard/MyPhoto/flap.png")
if (file.exists()){
   val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.absolutePath)
   imageView1.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
}
```

Заметьте что в таком случае в манифест нужно добавить `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`. Также для альтернативы можете использовать библиотеки для загрузки изображений такие как `Glide` или `Picasso`.

Comment: или Fresco можно

Comment: Уважаемый UjinUkr, я протестировал Ваш код, он не работает.

Comment: @Anton, что в логах?

Comment: var path: String = "sdcard/MyPhoto/flap.png"

   var file: File = File(path)

   if(file.exists()) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Yes!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    var bitmap: Bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.absolutePath)
    imageView1.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
   }
   else {
    Toast.makeText(this, "No!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
   }

Comment: Уважаемый UjinUkr, Не видит файл

Comment: @Anton, поексперементируйте с путем к файлу, также для правильного построения пути поможет Environment.(https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment)

Comment: Уважаемый UjinUkr, спасибо Вам! все дело в пути "mnt/extSdCard/MyPhoto/flap.png" Для Samsungov extSdCard, для других sdcard.